# first angular app deployment to a shared hosting

Tags: angular

I'm trying to deploy my first Angular app to my shared hosting but it just shows "It Works! NodeJS 10.24.1".

I've sent the inside files of "dist" folder to my hosting, created a node.js app from cPanel, installed the paths and the app domain but when I go to [www.example.com/my-app](http://www.example.com/my-app) ,
I'm seeing a white page just saying "It Works! NodeJS 10.24.1".

What do I need to do?

The app works normally on the local machine.

Comment: After you build angular what you ave in dist folder is like static html page. There won't be any dependency to nodejs. Place it like the same way you host simple html page

Comment: @GirishSadanandan At first, I tried it like that (just sent the files via cPanel File Manager to my hosting) and it showed just a blank page.

Comment: Check the errors at that showed on the console. When you got a blank page

Comment: @GirishSadanandan I'm sorry for the late reply. I'm getting this error on the JavaScript console: "Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 ()"
For the additional information: the app is working normally in localhost:4200